# Connecting to MySQL Before Starting Node/Express Server

Tags: node.js, express, promise, mysql2

I'm new to `Node` and trying to incorporate `mysql2/promises` into my Node (8.3.0)/Express (4.17) app but struggling to determine how to setup a connection pool prior to starting up the server.

**config.js**

```
module.exports = Object.freeze({
    DB_HOSTNAME: process.env.DB_HOSTNAME,
    DB_PORT: process.env.DB_PORT || 3306,
    DB_NAME: process.env.DB_NAME,
    DB_USERNAME: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
    DB_PASSWORD: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    SSL_CERT: process.env.SSL_CERT || './ssl/server.crt',
    SSL_KEY: process.env.SSL_KEY || './ssl/server.key',
    SERVER_PORT: process.env.SERVER_PORT || 443,
    STATIC_DIR: '/static'
});
```

**app.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const config = require('./config');
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');

const dbConfig = {
  connectionLimit: 10,
  host: config.DB_HOSTNAME,
  user: config.DB_USERNAME,
  password: config.DB_PASSWORD,
  database: config.DB_NAME,
  ssl: 'Amazon RDS'
};

const sslConfig = {
  key: fs.readFileSync(config.SSL_KEY),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(config.SSL_CERT)
};

const server = require('https').createServer(sslConfig, app);

// Start web server
server.listen(config.SERVER_PORT, () => {
  console.log('Web server started on port ' + config.SERVER_PORT);
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + config.STATIC_DIR));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

Do I need to call `mysql.createPool(dbConfig)` inside an async/await function?

Answer (score 0):

You can make pool connection in `mysql2-promise` with this code:

```
var db = require('mysql2-promise')();

db.configure({
    "host": "localhost",
    "user": "foo",
    "password": "bar",
    "database": "db"
});

db.pool.on('connection', function (poolConnection) {
    poolConnection.config.namedPlaceholders = true;
});

db.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE LIMIT = :limit', {limit: 10}).spread(function (users) {
    console.log('Hello users', users);
});
```

in `mysql` module when use, you should call `creatPool` for conection

example of `mysql` module

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 10,
  host            : 'example.org',
  user            : 'bob',
  password        : 'secret',
  database        : 'my_db'
});

pool.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log('The solution is: ', results[0].solution);
});
```